# Using start command to open new window with /V:ON enabled and also run a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to start a new window that is enabled with /V:ON and run a batch file.

```
start "Window Title" /D c:\workspace cmd '/V:ON & something.bat'
```

I can't get this to work though.

Comment: Remove the apostrophes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use single quotes:

```
 start "Window Title" /D c:\workspace "cmd /V:ON /c something.bat"
```